# Display dynamic text in an Android view

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm pretty new to developing Android applications but I am attempting to display the score at the end of a game I am making.

I was planning on switching to a view using:

```
setContentView(R.layout.over);
```

And that seems to work but I want to display the score.

I defined a textView:

```
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView02" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

But would like to change the text to read: "Score: (dynamic text from variable here)".
Obviously I need to reference that variable somehow, or set the text of the textView before changing to this view.

Please help!

Comment: You should remove the line android:text="@+id/TextView02" from the TextView in your layout file, as this is incorrect usage. The android:text parameter should be used to assign a literal string or a string defined in your strings.xml file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should solve your problem:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);  
tv.setText("Text to set");
```

Why do u assign to text and id the same values?

Comment: I'll check that out - 
Eclipse does that by default ;)

Comment: I'm getting a nullPointerException

Comment: did u add this code after setContentView and remove android:text="@+id/TextView02" ?

Answer (score 1):

Greg's Answer's pretty much what you want, but customized to what you are looking for:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
 tv.setText("Score: "+scoreVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I should use a dialog windows to show the Scrore. here ypou have how to create differents dialogs.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: use TextInputLayout with prefixText attribute